# Why can Android AlertDialog's width and height = -1

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have three questions to AlertDialog. First of all, I will post my code Then ask my question.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/l2"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:text="Test Test"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

This is the view to display in the AlertDialog, In the activity_main.xml, I have set a button to open the AlertDialog,The following is the code of listener.

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(view).create();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            Log.d("TAG", "First lp width and height" + lp.width + "  " + lp.height);
            dialog.show();
            Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
            dialogWindow.setLayout(500,500);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp2 = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
            Log.d("TAG", "lp2 width and height" + lp2.width + "  " + lp2.height);

        }
    });
```

The logcat information screenshot in the following:
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVDnq.png)
Question:

1. As you can see, The width and height of Dialog equals -1, I don't
   know the reason.
2. `dialogWindow.setLayout(500,500);` is executed after `dialog.show`.When I put  `dialogWindow.setLayout(500,500);` in front of  `dialog.show`, I find it does't work. Why
3. `getWindow.setLayout(int width, int height)`; What is the unit of the width and height?
   [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERgxw.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 & 2**
An alertdialog is not created until you call either `.show()` or `.create()` on it. So if you call the methods you're calling before creating it it will just return some default values.

If you do it like this

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(view).create();
dialog.create();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
Log.d("TAG", "First lp width and height" + lp.width + "  " + lp.height);
```

it should show the right values.

**3**
The same values as you would enter in xml. Can be `MATCH_PARENT`, `WRAP_CONTENT` or an exact value. The exact value is in pixels.

Also see [the docs for Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)

Comment: I think he asked what units are width and height (px, dp, sp ?) I'm curios to know that as well.

Comment: these are in pixels

Comment: I do it like what you suggest, I get the log which tell me that the width and height equal -2. And  I find another question that The attr --"layout_width" and "layout_height" of LinearLayout are useless. Could you tell me the reason.@TimCastelijns

Comment: @David.Cui my bad I misunderstood part of your question. Eugen's answer explains why

Comment: Anyway, Thx!@TimCastelijns

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, The width and height of Dialog equals -1, I don't know the reason.

`-1` is the default value for both `WindowManager.LayoutParams.width` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.height`.

`-1` is also known as `MATCH_PARENT` which means the dialog will try to occupy as much space while respecting theme attributes such as maximum and minimum width and height.

> `dialogWindow.setLayout(500,500)` is executed after `dialog.show()`. When I put it in front of `dialog.show()` it does't work. Why?

Before `dialog.show()` or `dialog.create()` the AlertDialog hasn't installed its content yet. It internally calls the following method of `PhoneWindow`:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    setContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

This should also explain where the default values come from. Your call to `setLayout` should now produce desired results.

Credit: [@TimCastelijns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843331/tim-castelijns)

> `getWindow.setLayout(int width, int height)` What is the unit of the width and height?

The unit is pixels. You can also use `WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT` constants.

If you're going to use this method avoid hardcoding pixels since on different screens you'd get different visual results. These methods will help you:

```
/** Precise decimal value, use for translation. */
public static float dpToPx(Context context, int dp) {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

/** Rounded down value, use for offsets, paddings, margins. */
public static int dpToPxOffset(Context context, int dp) {
    return (int) (dpToPx(context, dp));
}

/** Rounded up value, use for sizes. */
public static int dpToPxSize(Context context, int dp) {
    return (int) (0.5f + dpToPx(context, dp));
}
```

#### Notes:

The following lines are ignored.

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

`layout_` prefixed attributes are set on a `LayoutParams` object provided by parent view. Since there's no parent, there are no `LayoutParams` you can work with. Try setting `android:minHeight` and `android:minWidth` instead.

Parent view for root element is determined by parameter for inflation:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, /*parent*/ null);
```

Comment: Wow. Your notes arouse me. You are my hero!!! 
Another Question-What is the width of the LinearLayout depended on if it don't have `LayoutParams` to work with.

Comment: Default is always `match_parent` afaik. You probably want to add `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(view).create();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        Log.d("TAG", "First lp width and height" + lp.width + "  " + lp.height); <---------
        dialog.show();     <----------- you show the window here, so its size can be calculated. Before this, it doesn't exist. This is why you get -1 -1
        Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
        dialogWindow.setLayout(500,500);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp2 = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
        Log.d("TAG", "lp2 width and height" + lp2.width + "  " + lp2.height);

    }
});
```

Try with dialog.show before your first Log ;)

Comment: @Tim Castelijns answer is way better than mine.